# how to do Increment of numbers animation in xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiviewanimation

I want to animate increment of numbers starting from 1 to a limit (variable) , the duration of animation is 1.5 seconds. each time when I call the method this animation should work ( animate increment from 0 to (eg: 70 ).
int j=1;

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.5]; 
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];

do{
self.label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ï", j];
}

while(j<=limit);

 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Please help to animate the incrementing of the numbers.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do something like this. You can only animate the [animatable properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW2) of a view. These are: `frame`, `bounds`, `center`, `transform`, `alpha`, `backgroundColor` and `contentStretch`.

You want to use a [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) that updates the label every 1.5 seconds.

Probably something along those lines:

```
- (void)startAnimationWithLimit:(NSInteger)limit {
    self.limit = limit;
    self.timerFireCount = 0;
    [self.timer invalidate];        // stop timer if one is running already
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5f target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    self.timerFireCount++;
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.timerFireCount];
    if (self.timerFireCount > self.limit) {
        [timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
        self.label.text = @"Press start";
    }
}
```

and then start the timer with `[self startAnimationWithLimit:70];`

Comment: thank you so much..for the answer. Actually i am new to xcode